# Failure running MSTest.exe outside of Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, build, mstest

We want to have daily build which will also contain the automatic regression tests(webtests).

There are several problems doing that:

1)  When running it on build server without Visual Studio installed :

when running the command:
`mstest/testcontainer:regression.webtest`, getting the following error :

> "Loading Regression.webtest... File extension specified '.webtest' is not a valid test extension".

When running `mstest /testcontainer:regression.dll` no tests are found("No tests were found.")

2) When running it on machine with Visual Studio installed on :

we still can not run `mstest /testcontainer:regression.dll` The error: `(No tests were found)`.

`mstest /testcontainer:regression.webtest` works properly only if `regression.webtest` is small, but our regression.webtest` file is large and contains  many tests.

The error message is:

> An error occurred writing Web test result file
>   Failed to serialize WebTestResultDetails.. The Web test result details will be lost if the Web test result viewer window is closed.

We are using **Visual Studio 2013** Ultimate edition and **TFS 2013**.

Comment: We are having the same problem. We are building on Jenkins, but still have the same issue with running MSTEST from the command line on a machine with VS2013. Did you ever get any resolution?

Comment: Finally found a possible answer to my problem.  Not sure if it's a solution, but my problem had to do with us building a Windows Store App.  MSTEST does not work with WSA, only vstest.console.exe